# How to display CHM created by a SandCastle on web

Tags: .net, chm, sandcastle

I have a CHM file which includes a MSDN-library-like documentation for my .NET library and want to display it on the web.

Must have:

- display class library documentation similar to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045.aspx
- be able to search content

Preferable:

- ASP.NET application
- ability to tweak design/layout

I've found following:

- [X-Tensive Help Server](http://x-tensive.com/Products/HS/) - seems good, [looks nice](http://help.x-tensive.com/##HelpServer/External/User%20Guide.htm), but I'm unable to get any reply from their email support for two weeks. Probably spam filter issue :-(. Commercial.
- [Sand Castle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/). Direct publishing using SHFB (without CHM step) is what we are using now. [Ugly output](http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/Index.aspx?topic=html/8c0c97d0-c968-4c15-9fe9-e8f3a443c50a.htm). Free.

Could you recommend any other application/component/library/product which can do this?

Comment: Are you already using SHFB to publish directly to website format instead of to CHM? It's not clear from the question.

Comment: @Matthew Strawbridge: we use direct publishing without CHM. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could stick with SHFB and create a custom style (by hand) based on the vs-2005 one (which seems to be the only one that's actively maintained) that's more to your liking. You could use a custom Google search or similar on the site, or some local search engine component.